# writing terminal output to file

Tags: python, os.system

On my machine, I have some software which takes commands in the terminal and returns a list of values.

To run it, I have to type something like:

```
pdv -t filename
```

I am trying to run it as part of a python programme. When I run the following:

```
os.system('pdv -t %s' % (epoch_name))
```

then I get the values that I desire returned to my terminal (where epoch_name is the variable name for the filename). But when I try to write the result to a file:

```
os.system('pdv -t %s % "(epoch_name)" > 123.txt')
```

the file 123.txt is produced but it is empty.

I know that I am misplacing the " and/or ' characters, but I can't figure out where they should go.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.  Argument to `os.system()` should be a string representing command to the OS.

```
os.system('pdv -t %s > 123.txt' % epoch_name)
```

There is [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, which may worth look into if you are planning to process the output further in python.

Answer (score 9):

You can use subprocess.call, with the stdout keyword argument:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ls', '-l']

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=out)
```

Comment: Oh I like that more than my solution. `with` rocks. +1

Comment: Is that different than   out=open('output.txt','w') ?

Comment: @user1311069: I used the context manager interface of the file object.  See, for example, the first example here http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/ or here http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Comment: This worked but in the ipython notebook the terminal no longer pumps out information. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

Its better to use subprocess module that os.system

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['pdv', '-t', filename, '>', dest_file_name])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from subprocess import Popen
proc = Popen(['pdv', '-t', epoch_name], stdout = open('123.txt', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the command `script` is available to you. It might do what you need.

Comment: It is a unix/linux system command designed to capture console output of programs.

Comment: I don't have easy access to an apple.  Pull up a terminal and type `man script` and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `sys.stdout` check this document from [DiveIntoPython](http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/stdin_stdout_stderr.html) or the discussion [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1enj7r/sysstdoutwrite_in_python/) if it helps you out.

```
import sys

print 'Dive in'
saveout = sys.stdout
fsock = open('out.log', 'w')
sys.stdout = fsock
print 'This message will be logged instead of displayed'
sys.stdout = saveout
fsock.close()
```