# python write VLC log file (terminal return) using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, vlc

I'm trying to write the return of terminal in a file, called *debug.log*.
I would like also to get the pid to kill the process, for this moment the kill is working. 
But the debug.log is empty

```
cmd1 = "cvlc rtp://232.0.2.183:8200 --sout file/mkv:/media/file.mkv"
with open("/home/user/.cache/debug.log", 'w') as out:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=out, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
pid = proc.pid
with open("/home/user/.cache/pid.log", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(pid))
f.close()
```

Edit: I'm using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true?answertab=votes#tab-top) to kill the process
and this method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292594/writing-terminal-output-to-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)) to write the log:

```
    ###########kill the process############
    import os
    import signal
    import subprocess

    # The os.setsid() is passed in the argument preexec_fn so
    # it's run after the fork() and before  exec() to run the shell.
    pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

    os.killpg(pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups    

    ######### write the log #############
    import subprocess

    cmd = ['ls', '-l']       # example of command
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
        return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=out)
```

In fact, I would like to mix both of examples.
Thanks

Comment: Also, f.close() is redundant, as the 'with' keyword automatically closes the file for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the file is always empty... I'm trying differents things with your response

Comment: Trying to adapt this [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292594/writing-terminal-output-to-file?answertab=votes#tab-top), but not easy for me !

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope It will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the 'stderr' (not 'stdout') to 'out'.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stderr=out, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it's the same.
`with open("/home/user/.cache/debug.log", 'w') as subprocess.PIPE:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)`
The file is empty too

Comment: @Guillaume - I've added the code to access the output string as well.

Comment: @Guillaume - The code I've provided works for the test cases on my system, however, I can't replicate yours. I'm not sure what sort of terminal output you're getting now, and what you need. Read the subprocess docs and see if that helps - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: I think the return of vlc is different, I have to add "preexec_fn=os.setsid" to kill the process. But I don't know really what is this