# Capture output of os.system() in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I cannot use subprocess since I need to run a windows desktop shortcut. This works good for me:

```
os.system("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Neptune_Osprey_OCD_Daemon_xtensa_9.lnk")
```

I need to capture the output of the above desktop short which comes in command prompt. But I am unable to do it with os.system. Alternatively I tried with os.popen but still no success:

```
os.popen("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Neptune_Osprey_OCD_Daemon_xtensa_9.lnk" > output.log 2 > OCD_Open_Log.txt)
```

Comment: It should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292594/writing-terminal-output-to-file

Comment: why can't you use subprocess?

Comment: Since it is not an windows application, it is a desktop shortcut with proper attributes, therefore if I use subprocess it throws an error saying it is not a recognized windows application

Comment: `"some_string" > output.log 2 > OCD_Open_Log.txt` is not valid Python syntax. Did you mean for the rest of that line to be inside the string too?

Comment: No, I just want to store the output in a text file when the shortcut is run

Comment: Low-tech solution: right click the shortcut and choose properties. copy the contents of the "Target:" text box, and use that in  your `subprocess.check_output` call instead of the shortcut's path.

Comment: @Kevin, in the 'Target' of the shortcut I get this xml file: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3\xt-ocd.exe" -config topology_all_cpus_Opsrey_Neptune.xml"

Comment: I can put this to os.system, but how do I capture the output in a file ?

Comment: By putting it in `subprocess.check_output` instead of `system`. Remember to supply a list of strings as the first argument and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, just one step left:

```
 p = os.popen('"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Neptune_Osprey_OCD_Daemon_xtensa_9.lnk" 2> OCD_Log.txt') 
while 1:
 line = p.readline()
 if not line: break
 print line
```

This writes the output of the shortcut ran in command prompt to the OCD_Log.txt BUT only when I quit the command prompt by doing 'Ctrl + c'. And the OCD_Log.txt is also getting written with '^C' at the end of file.

The code is getting hanged because the application only quits when the command prompt is closed or Ctrl + c is done in the command prompt. Any suggestions to get over this last step ?

Comment: Even p.close() could not help. Ctrl-C seems to be inevitable. How do I give Ctrl-C through my script ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `popen`'s resulting object to read its output:

```
import os

p = os.popen('ls .')
stdout = p.read()
p.close()
```

Moreover, you could open command for reading **and** for writing, passing data to command's `stdin`!

```
p = os.popen('command', 'rw')
p.write(my_input)
my_output = p.read()
p.close()
```

Yet, using `popen` from `os` module is deprecated. But, limited by your condition *do not use `subprocess`, that makes no difference.